# Sum of values from aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a table in my component which has aura:iteration with rows. Each row has input. I need to summarise these all values. How can I do it?

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.listOfRecords}" var="record">
    <tr>
       <td><lightning:input aura:id="input" type="number" value="{!record.Price__c}"/></td>      
    </tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this we should just get array of all inputs by component.find() and go through the array and add oncommit event to input

```
<lightning:input aura:id="input" oncommit="{!c.commit}" type="number" value="{!record.Price__c}"/>

Controller: 
commit: function(component) {
    let pricesSum = 0;
    let changedPrices = component.find("input");

    changedPrices.forEach(element => {
        
        if (element.get("v.value")) {
            pricesSum += element.get("v.value");
        }
    });
}
```